# How can I prevent this navbar crashing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
        /* dropdown-menu related */
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }

        .nav > li a.dropdown-toggle {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
            min-width: 20px !important;
        }
        /* navbar icons */
        .nav {
        //  display: flex;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .nav > li {
            display: inline-block !important;
        }

        .nav_li_last_options {
            float: right;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .navbar-nav > li.nav_li_last_options {
                float: right;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .navbar-nav > li.nav_li_middle_toggle {
                float: left;
            }
        }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar_base">
    <div class="container-fluid padding_right_0">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar_ul_base" style="max-height: 50px;">
            <li><a href="#" style="padding: 15px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding: 15px; text-align: left">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown_menu_base">
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'm using bootstrap3 and jquery3.

**Problem:**
When I click `search icon`, the navbar shape is crashed.

Even it seems that `ul`tag's height will be larger when I click `search icon` and open dropdown-menu, I cannot know how to fix it.

**Question:**

How can I prevent this? And why this happened?

Comment: `.nav>li{vertical-align:top}`

Comment: The answer is on the duplicate ;) ... The comment was the quick fix if you don't have time to check the duplicate